# passing 1000 table records as in parameter procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, collections

I want to bulk insert data received from a procedure (around 1000 records). What's the best method for this?

table name : 
event_message
(msgid number,
msgdesc varchar2(1000),
created_by varchar2(100))

Comment: way too vague  _How_ are these 1000 records received by the procedure?  Where do the _originate_ and how do they arrive at being passed to the procedure for insert into the database?

Comment: 1000 records are passed as a array of records. How they can be used to bulk insert into table?